# problemas com scanf

Tags: c

Estou começando em C... e sempre acontece do compilador ignorar o `scanf`... mas não entendo o porque. Esse programa está dando esse erro e não estou conseguindo resolver, se puderem me ajudar, obrigada!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* O programa deve perguntar qual a figura geométrica, e então pedir para o
usuário digitar os tamanhos dos lados e calcular a area. 
*/

float quadrado(){
    float lado;

    printf("\nDigite o valor de cada lado: ");
    scanf("%f", &lado);
    
    return  printf("\nA area do quadrado é de %f", (lado*2 ));
};

float retangulo(){
    float base,altura;
    
    printf("\nDigite o valor da altura: ");
    scanf("%f", &altura);
    
    printf("\nDigite o valor da base: ");
    scanf("%f", &base);
    
    return  printf("A area do retangulo é de %f", (base*altura));
};

int main() {
    char figura;
    printf("Qual a figura geometrica? (quadrado ou retangulo)");
    scanf("%c", &figura);
    
    if(strcmp(&figura,"quadrado")){
        quadrado();
    } else if (strcmp(&figura,"retangulo")){
        retangulo();
    } else{
        printf("Figura invalida");
    }

}
```

Comment: Você está definindo sua função `quadrado` como retornando um `float` mas no comando `return` dessa função especifica o que será retornado pela função `printf` que, de acordo com o manual. será o número de bytes transmitidos. Talvez você quisesse retornar `lado*2`. Idem na função `retangulo`. Note que na função chamadora (main) você ignora o que é retornado por estas funções. Se é apenas para imprimir o que deseja em suas funções entaõ defina-as como `void` e imprima e não dê um `return`.

Comment: A área do quadrado não deveria ser `lado * lado`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em sua função principal, `figura` está declarado como um `char`.

"Char" é abreviação de Character, que é "Caractér" em inglês. É um formato de dado para representar apenas um caracter. Se você quer salvar uma string inteira, tem que reservar espaço para vários caracteres. A forma mais fácil de fazer isso, é na declaração da variável declarar um array deles:

```
char figura[30];
```

Nesse caso, separamos espaço na memória do computador para um array com 30 caracteres. Isso significa que sua string pode ter até no máximo 29 deles. Isso ocorre porque você precisa guardar um caracter que delimita o "final da string". Assim quando o computador chega nesse caracter, ele sabe que a string acabou na memória. Funções como `strcmp` que você usou precisam desse caracter terminador. Se você precisa de esclarecimentos nesse assunto recomendo fazer uma pesquisa aqui no site ou fazer outra pergunta.

Outra adaptação que você precisa fazer então é que a `flag`do `scanf` não deve mais ser `%c`. E sim `%s` para denotar uma string:

```
scanf("%s", figura);
```

Por último, como `figura` passou a ser um array, significa que não precisa mais do sinal `&` antes. A própria palavra `figura` já denota um ponteiro. Isso deve ser alterado nos `strcmp` e no `scanf`.

E com essas alterações seu programa roda da maneira adequada (e sem nenhum erro nem warning):

```
Qual a figura geometrica? (quadrado ou retangulo)quadrado                                                             
                                                                                                                      
Digite o valor da altura: 10                                                                                          
                                                                                                                      
Digite o valor da base: 10                                                                                            
A area do retangulo é de 100.000000
```

Comment: Obrigada! me ajudou mto..

Comment: @JuliaValente De nada! Não se esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita, caso ela tenha lhe respondido e ajudar eventuais buscas no site.

Answer (score -1):

Com as correções explicadas no comentário e corrigindo sua definição de string (array de caracteres e não um único caractere, veja se isto atende:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* O programa deve perguntar qual a figura geométrica, e então pedir para o
usuário digitar os tamanhos dos lados e calcular a area. 
*/

void quadrado(){
    float lado;

    printf("\nDigite o valor de cada lado: ");
    scanf("%f", &lado);
    
    printf("\nA area do quadrado é de %f", (lado*2 ));
};

void retangulo(){
    float base,altura;
    
    printf("\nDigite o valor da altura: ");
    scanf("%f", &altura);
    
    printf("\nDigite o valor da base: ");
    scanf("%f", &base);
    
    printf("A area do retangulo é de %f", (base*altura));
};

int main() {
    char figura[20];
    printf("Qual a figura geometrica? (quadrado ou retangulo)");
    scanf("%s", figura);
    
    if(strcmp(figura,"quadrado")){
        quadrado();
    } else if (strcmp(figura,"retangulo")){
        retangulo();
    } else{
        printf("Figura invalida");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda!!